# Test controller secured by oauth2Login() using mockMvc gets 302

Tags: spring-security, spring-oauth2

I want to test an endpoint secured by OAuth2. I have to adjust `AuthRequestResolver` and `TokenResponseClient` to meet the spec by adding extra parameters(http://www.hl7.org/fhir/smart-app-launch/#smart-authorization-sequence).

The endpoint is working and secured when running locally and in server environment.

About testing, I use
`mvc.perform(get("/endpoint").with(oauth2Login()));`

```kotlin
@WebMvcTest(MyController::class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class MyControllerTest(@Autowired val mvc: MockMvc) {
   @MockkBean
   private lateinit var myAuthRequestResolver: MyAuthRequestResolver

   @MockkBean
   private lateinit var myTokenResponseClient: MyAccessTokenResponseClient

   @MockkBean
   private lateinit var clientRegistrationRepository: ClientRegistrationRepository

   @MockkBean
   private lateinit var myServie: MyService


 @Test
 fun `should 200 when authenticated`() {
      every { myAuthRequestResolver.resolve(any()) } returns mockAuthorizationRequest()
      every { myService.get(any()) } returns "ok"

      mvc.perform(
         get("/endpoint")
            .with(oauth2Client())
//.with(oauth2Login()) also return 302
      )
         .andExpect(status().isOk())


fun mockAuthorizationRequest(): OAuth2AuthorizationRequest {
   val oAuth2AuthorizationRequest: OAuth2AuthorizationRequest = mockk()

   every { oAuth2AuthorizationRequest.grantType } returns AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE
   every { oAuth2AuthorizationRequest.authorizationRequestUri } returns "https://test"
   every { oAuth2AuthorizationRequest.authorizationUri } returns "https://test"
   every { oAuth2AuthorizationRequest.clientId } returns "test-client"
   every { oAuth2AuthorizationRequest.scopes } returns setOf("test")
   every { oAuth2AuthorizationRequest.additionalParameters } returns emptyMap()
   every { oAuth2AuthorizationRequest.redirectUri } returns "test"
   every { oAuth2AuthorizationRequest.state } returns "test"

   return oAuth2AuthorizationRequest
}
```

The test assertion error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<302>
Expected :200
Actual   :302
```

Which place should I look into further? I'm wondering about `myAuthRequestResolver` should not always return the same. Is there a better way?

Security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class OAuth2SecurityConfig @Autowired constructor(
   private val myAuthRequestResolver: MyAuthRequestResolver,
   private val myAccessTokenResponseClient: MyAccessTokenResponseClient): WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

   override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
      http.authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/endpoint**")
         .authenticated()
         .and()
         .csrf()
         .disable()
         .oauth2Login()
         .authorizationEndpoint()
         .authorizationRequestResolver(myAuthRequestResolver)
         .and()
         .tokenEndpoint()
         .accessTokenResponseClient(myAccessTokenResponseClient)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  every { myAuthRequestResolver.resolve(any()) } returns mockAuthorizationRequest()
```

should return null as

`every { myAuthRequestResolver.resolve(any()) } returns null`

because the request is already authenticated, authorizationRequest is null, and the test passes